# Access VBA Else without If

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to do an IF-THEN-ELSE condition in Access VBA within a For Loop. However I can't seem to get it to execute, what am I doing incorrectly? The code is as follows.

```
If m < 12 Then

For I = 2 To x

Price1 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I - 1)) ^ (m / 12))

Price2 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I)) ^ (m / 12))

  LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

  RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

  WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

  WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

  SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Else

For I = 2 To x

Price1 = Exp((vInterpRate(I - 1)) * (m / 12))

Price2 = Exp((vInterpRate(I)) * (m / 12))

End If
```

Executing this gives me a "Else Without If" error, which is confusing to me because there is an If - Then statement.

For context, here is the whole function.

```
Function EWMA(Lambda As Double) As Double

Dim Price1 As Double, Price2 As Double
Dim vInterpRate() As Variant
Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
Dim I As Long
Dim m As Double
Dim rec As Recordset


Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double

m = 3

Dim x As Integer

Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT InterpRate FROM HolderTable")

x = 0

Do While rec.EOF = False

x = x + 1

ReDim Preserve vInterpRate(x)

vInterpRate(x) = rec("InterpRate")


rec.MoveNext

Loop

If m < 12 Then

For I = 2 To x


Price1 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I - 1)) ^ (m / 12))

Price2 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I)) ^ (m / 12))

  LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

  RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

  WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

  WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

  SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Else

For I = 2 To x

Price1 = Exp((vInterpRate(I - 1)) * (m / 12))

Price2 = Exp((vInterpRate(I)) * (m / 12))

End If


Next I

EWMA = SumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Since you called the For loop inside the if, The next must be in that same IF block.  So put two `Next I`, one inside the If and the other inside the Else. And get rid of the one after the end if.

Comment: When is `m` ever >= 12? You declare it m = 3 and it never changes. Hence, no need for if/then/else block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close here, you just have the looping portion or "Next I" part in the wrong spot. Try:

```
If m < 12 Then
    For I = 2 To x
        Price1 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I - 1)) ^ (m / 12))
        Price2 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I)) ^ (m / 12))
        LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)
        RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2
        WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)
        WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ
        SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn
    Next I
Else
    For I = 2 To x
        Price1 = Exp((vInterpRate(I - 1)) * (m / 12))
        Price2 = Exp((vInterpRate(I)) * (m / 12))
    Next I
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider using a recordset, array, or loops and call the VBA function directly from an SQL query which is allowable in MSAccess.exe (not via ODBC/OLEDB). The challenge of your needs is the need to look one row up with row counts which can be handled with subqueries. Below assumes an autonumber ID field. Though queries used derived tables (nested `SELECT` in `FROM` clause), such derived tables can be saved as their own SQL stored queries.

**SQL** Query *(notice VBA function called in-line with scalar Lambda value at 0.015)*

```sql
SELECT Sum(final.WtdRtn) ^ (1/2) As EWMA

FROM    
   (SELECT dT.CurrInterpRate, dT.LastInterpRate, dT.RowCount,
           EWMA(0.015, dT.CurrInterpRate, dT.LastInterpRate, dT.RowCount) As WtdRtn
    FROM    
        (SELECT HolderTable.ID, HolderTable.InterpRate As CurrInterpRate,

               (SELECT TOP 1 HolderTable.InterpRate FROM HolderTable sub 
                WHERE sub.ID < HolderTable.ID
                ORDER BY sub.ID DESC) As LastInterpRate,

               (SELECT Count(*) FROM HolderTable sub 
                WHERE sub.ID < HolderTable.ID) As RowCount

         FROM HolderTable
        ) As dT

   ) As final
```

**VBA** Function *(to be saved in standard module not any specific object (form/report); notice change of return value as aggregation is run in SQL)*

```
Public Function EWMA(Lambda As Double, currRowIR As Double, _
                     lastRowIR As Double, rowCount As Long) As Double

    Dim Price1 As Double, Price2 As Double
    Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim m As Double: m = 3

    Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double

    If m < 12 Then

          Price1 = 1 / ((1 + lastRowIR) ^ (m / 12))
          Price2 = 1 / ((1 + currRowIR) ^ (m / 12))
          LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)
          RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2
          WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (rowCount)
          WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

    Else
          Price1 = Exp(lastRowIR * (m / 12))
          Price2 = Exp(currRowIR * (m / 12))
    End If

    EWMA = WtdRtn

End Function
```

---

Even still, you may be able to run it all in SQL without VBA. Here, *Lambda* and *m* is passed as scalars. Of course without data, I cannot fully test:

```
SELECT Sum(final.WtdRtn) ^ (1/2) As EWMA

FROM    
    (SELECT 1 / ((1 + dT.lastRowIR) ^ (dT.m / 12)) As Price1, 
            1 / ((1 + dT.currRowIR) ^ (dT.m / 12)) As Price2,
            Log(Price1 / Price2) As LogRtn, LogRtn ^ 2 As RtnSQ, 
            (1 - dT.Lambda) * dT.Lambda ^ (dT.rowCount) As WT,
            WT * RtnSQ As WtdRtn
     FROM    
         (SELECT HolderTable.ID, HolderTable.InterpRate As currRowIR,

                 (SELECT TOP 1 HolderTable.InterpRate FROM HolderTable sub 
                  WHERE sub.ID < HolderTable.ID
                  ORDER BY sub.ID DESC) As lastRowIR,

                 (SELECT Count(*) FROM HolderTable sub 
                  WHERE sub.ID < HolderTable.ID) As rowCount

                 3 As m,

                 0.015 As Lambda

         FROM HolderTable
        ) As dT

    ) As final
```

Comment: What's the point of the if m<12 if you set m= 3 right before? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Indeed, no point as OP did just that with very comment I raised. I kept for comparison. Notice final query only take m=3.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments. `m=3` in all cases, so why bother with the if/else/end if. However, here's an additional observation that should get the if/end if in a correct order if you choose to use it.

You use multiple cases of `for I=2 to x`. As I understand, you can get away with using it only once?

```
For I = 2 To x
If m < 12 Then
    Price1 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I - 1)) ^ (m / 12))
    Price2 = 1 / ((1 + vInterpRate(I)) ^ (m / 12))
    LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)
    RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2
    WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)
    WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ
    SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn
Else
    Price1 = Exp((vInterpRate(I - 1)) * (m / 12))
    Price2 = Exp((vInterpRate(I)) * (m / 12))

End If
Next I
```